# Show that $\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^{2}+1\rangle$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a theorem that states "If $R$ is a commutative ring with unity, and I is an ideal of $R$, then $R/I$ is a field iff I is a maximal ideal."

I would like to use this theorem to prove the proposition in the title. To do this, I first need to show that $\Bbb R[x]$ is a commutative ring with unity, and then that $\langle x^{2}+1\rangle$ is a maximal ideal (without using irreducibility, which we have not covered yet).

Questions:

1) How do I show that $\Bbb R[x]$ is commutative?

2) How do I show that $\langle x^{2}+1\rangle $ is a maximal ideal without irreducibility?

Comment: Hello. Please consider learning MathJax typesetting. Also what have you tried in solving the problem?

Comment: Start with the definitions. What do "commutative", "maximal ideal" and "irreducible" mean?

Comment: Is $R[X]=\mathbb{R}[X]$ in this situation?

Comment: I've corrected a few things about the formatting. Can you confirm that I haven't changed the meaning of your question (especially regarding Mark's comment and the first line of egreg's answer)? Feel free to rollback otherwise, of course.

Comment: @ArnaudD. The meaning looks to be the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that the ring $R$ you're mentioning is the real field $\mathbb{R}$.

Commutativity of $R[x]$, where $R$ is a commutative ring is just verification.

Suppose $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ but $f(x)\notin\langle x^2+1\rangle$. You want to show that $f(x)+\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is invertible as an element of $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

By the division algorithm, you can write
$$
f(x)=(x^2+1)g(x)+a+bx
$$
so it is not restrictive to assume $f(x)=a+bx$. Note that one among $a$ and $b$ is nonzero, because $f(x)\notin\langle x^2+1\rangle$. In particular, $a^2+b^2\ne0$. Compute
$$
(a+bx)\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}x\right)
$$
and conclude.

Comment: Are you supposed to get $x^2$ if you calculate $(a+bx)\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}x\right)$ ?

Comment: Because I get $\frac{(a+bx)(a-bx)}{(a+b)(a-b)}$ What should I conclude from taht or did I calculate wrong?

Comment: @New2Math You get $\frac{a^2-b^2x^2}{a^2+b^2}=1-\frac{b^2}{a^2+b^2}(1+x^2)$, so in the quotient ring this becomes $1+\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

To show commutativity you simply use the fact that $\Bbb R$ is commutative, and show that, for $f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{d_1}a_nx^n$ and $g(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{d_2}b_nx^n$ we have $f(x)g(x)=g(x)f(x)$, where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the degrees of $f$ and $g$, respectively.

To show that $I:=\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is maximal in $\Bbb R[x]$ one could use the following argument. Suppose there is an ideal $J:I\subseteq J\subseteq\Bbb R[x]$. Now suppose that $J\neq I$. Then there exists $p(x)\in J:p(x)\notin I$. Hence, $x^2+1\nmid p(x)$. From this we see that $x^2+1$ and $p(x)$ are relatively prime, since the only factors of $x^2+1$ in $\Bbb R[x]$ are $1$ and $x^2+1$ (and their associates). Hence, $\exists u(x),v(x)\in\Bbb R[x]:p(x)u(x)+(x^2+1)v(x)=1$, and since $p(x)\in J\implies p(x)u(x)\in J$ and $(x^2+1)\in I\implies (x^2+1)\in J\implies (x^2+1)v(x)\in J$, we must have $1\in J$. Since $1\in J$, we must have $J=\Bbb R[x]$. Therefore, $I$ must be a maximal ideal of $\Bbb R[x]$.